# wicket model not affected to a value

Tags: listview, wicket-6

I am working in Wicket Framework. I created a list of data I put on a listview.
For each component, I add a Model with the Model of one element of my list of Class which contains the value.
Once I save my form I collect each element of my list to save on my database. The list is empty without changed values. Can you explain why?

Here some part of my code to understand the issue:

List is a global variable on my class:

```
public List<ShowFormData> listofdata;
```

Here I fill the list:

```
listofdata = new ArrayList<>();
//we list all empty data
for (ExtensibleTemplateElement extensibleTemplateElementList1 : extensibleTemplateElementList) {
                listofdata.add(new ShowFormData(extensibleTemplateElementList1.getDataFieldName(), null, "", "", Boolean.FALSE, extensibleTemplateElementList1, extensibleTemplateElementList1.getExtensibleDataType().getExtensibleDataTypeId(), Boolean.FALSE, 0));
}
```

Here I affect my component with a element of my list

```
 listview = new ListView<Object>("list", listofdata) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<Object> li) {
            final ShowFormData showformData = (ShowFormData) li.getModelObject();

            ....

            li.add(new TextField("textfield", new Model<String>(showformData.getData())));
            ....

            li.add(new TextArea("textaera", new Model<String>(showformData.getData())));

            ....

  }
 }
```

Here when I save when I press an AjaxButton

```
 AjaxButton savebutton;
 savebutton = (AjaxButton) new AjaxButton("save_ext", form) {

        @Override
        protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            super.onError(target, form); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            System.out.println("save button ajax error it is impossible to save");
            //target.appendJavaScript("stopLoading();");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {

        ....

        for (int i = 0; i < listofdata.size(); i++) {
        ....

        extensibleDatum.setValue(listofdata.get(i).getData());
        extensibleFormBO.save(extensibleDatum); 
        ....
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using ListView in a Form you have to call `listView.setReuseItems(true)` - https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/cab6795aa64fe2280a938f69bb304255f2fc9bbe/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.java#L84

Instead of using `new Model<String>(showformData.getData())` you have to use `new PropertyModel<String>(showformData, "data"))`. This way the new value will be saved in the ShowFormData's data field.

Use ListView to avoid casts.

Comment: listview with setReuseItems(true) and still the same behaviour: I cannot get the data from the model.

Comment: This is the right thing to do, but the values of all models do not update. Once I call onSubmit of my AjaxButton I have only old values. My form is called by a previous AjaxButton. Does my form be affected by this call?